# Windows 8.1 not in Fedora 20 boot

Tags: fedora

So I installed a Linux distro, Fedora 20, for the first time. After installing Fedora there was no way for me to boot into Windows 8.1, which was already installed. I have tried many things, to no avail. What do I do?

Comment: What did you try specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have experience with setting up dual boot? It is very likely that you installed Fedora 20 and wiped out the Windows Operating System. If this is the case, you would need to reinstall Windows.

The reason you were not able to install the OS as a dual boot is because Windows will typically by installed, allocating all hard drive space to itself on the drive that you are installing it on. When you chose to install Fedora 20 on the drive, you overwrote the Windows 8.1 OS irreversibly.

You will likely need to revert to your backups if you have image level backups.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Do what? Revert to an image level backup or re-install the Windows 8.1 operating system? It appears you are asking how to be a tech. If the terminology I am referring to is too complex, you may need to hire someone to do this for you. It's like asking a home builder how to build a house when you have no experience with it, and only have experience with small DIY projects around the house. Fedora 20 is not a program, it is an operating system.

Comment: Revert to backup

Comment: Did you make an image level of your computer? If not, then you can't do that since the image level backup doesn't exist.

Comment: I have no idea what that is

Comment: Take your computer to a professional (not Geek Squad). You are not suitable to complete this level of work. If you know what Fedora 20 is and you have a purpose for it, then ask the professional to set your computer up for dual boot with Windows 8.1 re-installed and Fedora 20. If you have no idea what Fedora 20 is, then just ask for Windows 8.1 to be re-installed. It would take an obnoxiously long time for me to walk you through the process and most techs would expect to be paid for this task. Please note that the tech's on this site are volunteering their time to help.

Comment: If you don't really care about Windows, just continue to use Fedora 20 and get used to it. Fedora is a perfectly good operating system. In my opinion, Linux Mint is easier for computer illiterate people to get used to.